# How do I get Bower to install a file to a specified path and name?

Tags: javascript, bower

I have the following bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "dependencies": {
    "stripe": "https://js.stripe.com/v2/"
  }
}
```

This grabs the javascript at the associated url and creates the following file:

```
/bower_components/stripe/index
```

Note that the file is not `index.js`, but simply `index`. This is problematic, as my Brocfile refuses to use the `index` file, insisting that it has to be `index.js`. If I manually change the name to `index.js`, then the application works fine. Obviously, this isn't a satisfactory solution.

So is there a way to get bower to install the file as `index.js` rather than `index`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set a different folder for bower you can create a `.bowerrc` file with the following:

```
{
    "directory": "public/bower"
}
```

I'm not exactly sure of your environment, but for example if you have node.js you can create a gulp.js setup which would do the rename before whatever other processes you need to run.

quasi example `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('prep', function () {
  gulp.src('public/bower/stripe/index', {
      base: 'public/bower/stripe'
    })
    .pipe(rename('index.js'));
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: sidenote: I'm not very familiar with `broccoli`, but it looks like `gulp` could replace it as an asset builder? I use `gulp` to minify/uglify/concat/rename, etc for my assets.